# How to disable the 0.0 numbers below the X axis that are appearing behind the months labels?

Tags: swift, ios-charts

How to disable the 0.0 numbers below the X axis that are appearing behind the month's labels?
I tried to disable some xAxis properties but didn't work, I am using IOS charts.

```
@IBOutlet weak var chartView: BarChartView!

var completedGoals = [Double]()
var totalGoals = [Double]()
let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC"]

func configure() {
    chartView.delegate = self as? ChartViewDelegate
    chartView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    chartView.drawBarShadowEnabled = false
    chartView.drawValueAboveBarEnabled = false

    let xAxis = chartView.xAxis
    xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    xAxis.centerAxisLabelsEnabled = true
    xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values:months)
    xAxis.granularity = 1
    xAxis.labelCount = 12

    let leftAxisFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    leftAxisFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1

    let yaxis = chartView.leftAxis
    yaxis.spaceTop = 0.35
    yaxis.axisMinimum = 0
    yaxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false

    chartView.rightAxis.enabled = false

    setChart()
}

func setChart() {
    var dataEntries1 = [BarChartDataEntry]()
    var dataEntries2 = [BarChartDataEntry]()
    let xValuesForTotalGoals = [0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5,9.5,10.5,11.5]

    totalGoals = data.monthly(goals: data.allGoalsObjects(achieved: false))
    completedGoals = data.monthly(goals: data.allGoalsObjects(achieved: true))
    for i in 0..<months.count {
        dataEntries1.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: xValuesForTotalGoals[i], y: totalGoals[i]))
        dataEntries2.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: completedGoals[i]))
    }
    let chartDataSet1 = BarChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries1, label: "Total Number Of Goals")
    let chartDataSet2 = BarChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries2, label: "Completed Goals")
    chartDataSet1.colors = [UIColor.black]
    chartDataSet1.valueTextColor = UIColor.white
    chartDataSet2.colors = [UIColor.gray]
    let chartData = BarChartData(dataSets: [chartDataSet1, chartDataSet2])
    let barWidth = 0.5
    chartData.barWidth = barWidth
    chartView.notifyDataSetChanged()
    chartView.data = chartData
    chartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 1.5, yAxisDuration: 1.5, easingOption: .linear)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember what property is, try with each one

```
xAxis.enabled = false.
rightAxis.enabled = false.
```

Comment: no I want to keep the xAxis but with only months labels underneath. there are 0.0 numbers appearing with months labels as you can see and I've know idea why do they appear in the first place, I want to hide them. thanks @AndresGomez